# What's the different between as? Implementor vs as Implementor?

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, we have `as` and `as?`

What's the different between the below

```
(origin as? Implementor)?.someFunction()
```

vs

```
(origin as Implementor?)?.someFunction()
```

Or they are essentially the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`as?` casts the left side to the class on the right side and returns `null` if it is not possible. `as` does the same but throws an exception if the cast is not possible.

In your first example you check if `origin` is of the type `Implementor` and if so, you call `someFunction()`. The line will never throw an exception, means if `object` is `null` or from another type it will do nothing.

In the second example you you cast `origin` to type `Implementor` or `null` and if it is not null, you call `someFunction()`. If the object is from another type the line throws an exception.